# Return record key from InsertAsync in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, database, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm trying to return the key of the match created / updated in VS2022 using Xamarin on Android.

The below code works perfectly, but returns the amount of rows updated / inserted.

```
public class GameDatabase
{
    readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public void SaveGame()
    {
        Task<DBMatch> matchResult = SaveGameAsync(dbMatch);
        _match.matchKey = matchResult.Result.matchKey;
    }

    public Task<int> SaveMatchAsync(DBMatch dbMatch)
    {
        if (dbMatch.matchKey != 0)
        {
            // Update an existing Game.
            return database.UpdateAsync(dbMatch);
        }
        else
        {
            // Save a new Game.
            return database.InsertAsync(dbMatch);
        }
   }
}
```

How do I update it to return the key? I seem to have gone round the houses about 20 times changing it to async and await as I believe the object is updated with the key, but then it just hangs on await.

e.g.

```
    public async Task<DBMatch> SaveGameAsync(DBMatch dbMatch)
    {
        if (dbMatch.matchKey != 0)
        {
            // Update an existing Game.
            await database.UpdateAsync(dbMatch);
        }
        else
        {
            // Save a new Game.
            await database.InsertAsync(dbMatch);
        }
        return dbMatch;
    }
```

Comment: What is `database` and what does `InsertAsync` actually do? You say it hangs when you use the second code, but it's essentially the same as the first one. How are you calling the `SaveGameAsync` method? Are you `await`ing all the way up the chain or do you have a `.Result` in there somewhere? This sounds like an async deadlock.

Comment: @DavidG database is a SQLiteAsyncConnection. Hopefully updated the code enough to answer your questions. With the hanging, it never completes the await line. I thought it might be down to the fact InsertAsync returns a Task and await is essentially the same kind of thing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Blocking async operations to create "synchronous" ones is a bug that can *does* lead to deadlocks. Either use `SaveMatchAsync` only, or use only blocking methods in  `SaveGame`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the answer was to not use async or Tasks at all, and instead just use Wait().

```
DBMatch matchResult = SaveGameAsync(dbMatch);
_match.matchKey = matchResult.matchKey;

public DBMatch SaveGameAsync(DBMatch dbMatch)
{
    if (dbMatch.matchKey != 0)
    {
        // Update an existing Game.
        database.UpdateAsync(dbMatch).Wait();
    }
    else
    {
        // Save a new Game.
        database.InsertAsync(dbMatch).Wait();
    }
    return dbMatch;
}
```

Comment: Using Wait on a Task is rarely correct. https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/10/a-tour-of-task-part-5-wait.html